# ACTION_FOUND Broadcast inside bound service

Tags: java, android, service, bluetooth

To create Broadcast receiver I need to get context but context is absent in the bound service. I create new class with broadcast receiver inside and describe it by statically way in manifest -

```
<receiver android:name=".SingBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action,ACTION_FOUND"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But again, the receiver need context... I am not sure even in the receiving broadcast request. So, please, may be somebody know how to create receiver for ACTION_FOUND (startdiscovery) inside bound service?

Comment: So you mean that ((Context)this).registerReceiver(.....)  will work for remote bounded service builded on AIDL?

Comment: I do not ask what is base class of base for service - off course it is Context, my question about of registering broadcast receiver.

Comment: I mean that if you will work with ordinary local service then activity and service are in the same APK. So if you have context for activity and other context for local service then it is possible call for every of this context method getApplicationContext, the resul will be the same. But bounded service has its own APK that is another then Activity APK, so result of getApplicationContext more various and not predictable especially that class Context is not parcelable.